# How do I do a type check in ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I tried `if(string? myStr)` but that gives a syntax error in the editor. How do I do a type check in Ballerina ?

Comment: Please include the origin of `myStr` and the *exact* error message (as text, not as a screenshot).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the type guard statement for that,

Eg:

```
    if (myStr is string) {
       io:println("This is String");
    } else {
       io:println("This isn't String");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your use case for checking type?

As per the spec types and values is determined automatically based on their structure

> Ballerina’s type system is much more flexible than traditional
>   statically typed languages. First, it is structural: instead of
>   requiring the program to explicitly say which types are compatible
>   with each other, compatibility of types and values is determined
>   automatically based on their structure; this is particularly useful in
>   integration scenarios that combine data from multiple,
>   independently-designed systems. Second, it provides union types: a
>   choice of two or more types. Third, it provides open records: records
>   that can contain fields in addition to those explicitly named in its
>   type definition. This flexibility allows it also to be used as a
>   schema for the data that is exchanged in distributed applications.
>   Ballerina’s data types are designed to work particularly well with
>   JSON; any JSON value has a direct, natural representation as a
>   Ballerina value. Ballerina also provides support for XML and
>   relational data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type switch (match) statement or the expression version of the match statement here. Here is an example.

```
import ballerina/io;

function main (string... args) {
    any a = "some string value";

    // If the type of the variable a is string executes the first block, if not the second block.
    match a {
        string s => { io:println("string type");} 
        any k => {io:println("any other type");}
    }
}
```

Please refer the following example for more information. 
https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/match.html

Comment: This example doesn't compile with Ballerina 1.0. I assume this feature is pre-1.0 and doesn't exists in Ballerina 1.0. Ballerina 1.0 implements _type test expression_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is likely a sub-optimal answer (i.e. not covering all the aspects) but I have found out that in Ballerina 1.0 (that implements language specification 2019R3) one can use *type test expression*.

The best documentation I have found is:

- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/type-test-expression.html
- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/type-guard.html

Here's a working Ballerina 1.0 example with *union* and *any* types:

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    // union type
    int|error a = 0;
    io:print("typeof a: ");
    io:println(typeof a); // typeof expression

    // type test expression
    if (a is int) {
        io:println("a is int");
    } else {
        io:println("a is error");
    }

    // any type
    any b = "string";
    io:print("typeof b: ");
    io:println(typeof b); // typeof expression

    // type test expression
    if (b is int) {
        io:println("b is int");
    } else if (b is string) {
        io:println("b is string");
    } else {
        io:println("b is something else");
    }
}
```

Prints when run:

```
$ ballerina run test.bal 
typeof a: typedesc int
a is int
typeof b: typedesc string
b is string
```